# Handling Yahoo Finance Quotes Hash in Rails 3 - the Sequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yahoo

A) Controller code :

```
  def show
    @quote_list = params[:symbol]
    puts @quote_list

    require 'yahoofinance'

    quote_type = YahooFinance::StandardQuote

    quote_symbols = @quote_list

    @quote_info = YahooFinance::get_quotes( quote_type, quote_symbols ) do |qt|
      puts qt.symbol
      puts qt.bid.to_s
      puts qt.ask.to_s
    end
  end
```

The part that accesses the Yahoo Finance hash is at the bottom - I have used this to drive an sms service in anothe routine.The View code consists of :

```
<p>Stock Symbol(s) Requested: <%= @quote_list %> </p>
<p>Quote Details : </p> <%= @quote_info %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Stock Symbol</th>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Bid</th>
    <th>Ask</th>
    <th>Last Trade</th>
    <th>Trade Price</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @quote_list.each do |stock| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= stock.symbol %></td>
    <td><%= stock.name %></td>
    <td><%= stock.bid.to_s %></td>
    <td><%= stock.ask.to_s %></td>
    <td><%= stock.lastTradeTime.to_s %></td>
    <td><%= stock.lastTrade %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The compile error is shown below :

```
SyntaxError in Screenquotes#show

Showing /home/lvl9/waf_projects/squotes_app/app/views/screenquotes/show.html.erb where line #24 raised:

compile error
/home/lvl9/waf_projects/squotes_app/app/views/screenquotes/show.html.erb:24: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR
...buffer.append= ( stock.@symbol );@output_buffer.safe_concat(...
                              ^

Extracted source (around line #24):

21: 
22: <% @quote_list.each do |stock| %>
23:   <tr>
24:     <td><%= stock.@symbol %></td>
25:     <td><%= stock.name %></td>
26:     <td><%= stock.bid.to_s %></td>
27:     <td><%= stock.ask.to_s %></td> 


Listing of @quote_info instance variable hash contents from rails console session shown below :

irb(main):051:0> quote_symbols = "goog,yhoo"
=> "goog,yhoo"
irb(main):052:0>  @quote_info = YahooFinance::get_quotes( quote_type, quote_symbols )
```

> {"GOOG"=>#563.00", @dayHigh=574.27, @tickerTrend=" =-+=== ", @date="11/25/2011", @averageDailyVolume=3120350, @name="Google Inc.", @volume=1562341, @formathash={"v"=>["volume", "val.to_i"], "a"=>["ask", "val.to_f"], "l"=>["lastTradeWithTime", "val"], "b"=>["bid", "val.to_f"], "m"=>["dayRange", "val"], "p2"=>["changePercent", "val.to_f"], "d1"=>["date", "val"], "t7"=>["tickerTrend", "convert(val)"], "c1"=>["changePoints", "val.to_f"], "c"=>["change", "val"], "n"=>["name", "val"], "o"=>["open", "val.to_f"], "p"=>["previousClose", "val.to_f"], "l1"=>["lastTrade", "val.to_f"], "a2"=>["averageDailyVolume", "val.to_i"], "g"=>["dayLow", "val.to_f"], "t1"=>["time", "val"], "h"=>["dayHigh", "val.to_f"], "s"=>["symbol", "val"]}, @time="1:00pm", @open=565.19, @bid=0.0, @change="-7.11 - -1.25%", @ask=620.0, @dayLow=561.33, @changePercent=-1.25, @lastTrade=563.0>, "YHOO"=>#15.10", @dayHigh=15.25, @tickerTrend=" ====== ", @date="11/25/2011", @averageDailyVolume=32945700, @name="Yahoo! Inc.", @volume=10781728, @formathash={"v"=>["volume", "val.to_i"], "a"=>["ask", "val.to_f"], "l"=>["lastTradeWithTime", "val"], "b"=>["bid", "val.to_f"], "m"=>["dayRange", "val"], "p2"=>["changePercent", "val.to_f"], "d1"=>["date", "val"], "t7"=>["tickerTrend", "convert(val)"], "c1"=>["changePoints", "val.to_f"], "c"=>["change", "val"], "n"=>["name", "val"], "o"=>["open", "val.to_f"], "p"=>["previousClose", "val.to_f"], "l1"=>["lastTrade", "val.to_f"], "a2"=>["averageDailyVolume", "val.to_i"], "g"=>["dayLow", "val.to_f"], "t1"=>["time", "val"], "h"=>["dayHigh", "val.to_f"], "s"=>["symbol", "val"]}, @time="1:00pm", @open=15.05, @bid=13.5, @change="+0.16 - +1.07%", @ask=0.0, @dayLow=14.9, @changePercent=1.07, @lastTrade=15.1>} I am trying to display the symbol, bid ,ask, lasttrade and last trade price for each member ( ie Goog and Yhoo) from this hash in the loop in the view file.

I hope this makes things clearer - help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `@symbol` when it should be just `symbol`, the same as all the other class variables you access in the same template.

*edit* The @quote_list variable is just the stock symbols, not the returned quote information. The returned information is in @quote_info, which does not contain the symbol as a hash key.

You may either iterate over the symbols and use each symbol to access the corresponding hash value, or iterate over the hash using both a key *and* value in the block; the key will be the symbol.

If you don't care about order, iterating over the hash is easiest.

```
<% @quote_info.each do |symbol, info| %>
    <%= symbol %> <%= info.open %>
... etc ...
```

If you *do* care about order, then order the list of symbols however you want, iterate over them, and retrieve each symbol's related info:

```
<% @quote_symbols.each do |symbol| %>
  <% info = @quote_info[symbol] %>
... etc ...
```

Comment: Did anybody see my comment re above - sent the wrong compile error - got same error with symbol without the @ prefix must be something peculiar to Yahoo feed - but can't see it.

Comment: @JoeMcGouran I don't see how you could get the *same* error, but see update.

Comment: Dave, I am a Rails neophyte - what will the remaining code inside the loop look like . Help really appreciated.

Comment: @JoeMcGouran The same as it does now, but using "info".

Comment: Dave, many thanks for your assistance - you saved my life and my hair.